# Why is the resident set size (RSS) of my program larger than the executable?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management

Running a simple program that simple waits in a while loop and I was curious to know the memory stats of the process. The program I am running is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
    }
return 0;
}
```

when compiled the above program produces an executable file of 7950 bytes(2 pages approx). But `/proc/pid/statm` gives rss size as 72 pages? Can anyone give some insight here?

Regards,
Meraj

Comment: Thanks Arun! I was unable to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More things will need to be resident in memory than just the code and data segments from your executable file while the program is running. For example, it's likely to also have resident memory pages from the stack, the heap, shared libraries, and file mappings.

If you want to see how the resident pages are being used, you could look at `/proc/<pid>/smaps` -- specifically the *Rss:* field.

`/proc/<pid>/maps` (no 's') will give you a more readable overview of the mappings of the process. Note that e.g. the stack (or stacks in case of many threads) and the heap count as mappings too.

Here's some example output for `cat /proc/self/maps` (which will print the mappings for the `cat` process itself). I've added arrows on the right (might need to scroll) to explain what some of the different mappings are. Once you know that, you can check out `cat /proc/<pid>/smaps` to see what the resident size of each mapping is.

```
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3409248            /bin/cat                            <- text (code) segment
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 3409248            /bin/cat                            <- read-only data segment (for e.g. string literals)
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 3409248            /bin/cat                            <- read/write data segment
01d6a000-01d8b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                  [heap]
7f23d2b5c000-7f23d3328000 r--p 00000000 08:01 8126750    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive      <- memory-mapped file (actually, executables and
                                                                                                shared libraries are memory-mapped files too)
7f23d3328000-7f23d34e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11155466   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so  ^
7f23d34e2000-7f23d36e1000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 11155466   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so  | Various mappings for
7f23d36e1000-7f23d36e5000 r--p 001b9000 08:01 11155466   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so  | glibc
7f23d36e5000-7f23d36e7000 rw-p 001bd000 08:01 11155466   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so  v
7f23d36e7000-7f23d36ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                              <- Anonymous mapping (MAP_ANONYMOUS)
...
7fffbc234000-7fffbc255000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
7fffbc3a1000-7fffbc3a3000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]                              ^
7fffbc3a3000-7fffbc3a5000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [vvar]                              | Internal stuff related to how some
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  [vsyscall]                          v system calls are implemented
```

Comment: Thank you Ulfalizer. So do you mean that the task_struct the keeps tracks of all the process related statistics sums up all the mappings per process to get rss size??

Comment: @MerajHussain: I'm not sure exactly where `/proc/<pid>/<statm>` gets the information, but yeah, it probably just shows the total rss of all the mappings.

Comment: ...and any time you see "rss for process *x*", then that is likely to mean (or at least approximate) the total rss of all the mappings. (There might be some subtleties that I'm not aware of.) Inspecting the rss of each mapping will give you an idea of where memory is being used at least.